# Plotting structure array in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I have a structure array (98*1) in MATLAB:

[image]

Now I am trying to plot a graph by using 2 particular fields (say x and y). The values of x and y are present on each of these 98 rows. Trying the following command to plot gives error.

```
plot(ans{1:98,1}.x,ans{1:98,1}.y)
```

> Expected one output from a curly brace or dot indexing expression, but
>   there were 98 results.
>
> Error in just (line 1) plot(ans{1:98,1}.x,ans{1:98,1}.y)

Need help in knowing what I am doing wrong, and how to correct it.

Comment: Nusrat, please read the "unsolicited advice" that I just added to my answer. I really think you need to rethink how you save your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need [`cellfun`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) with an [anonymous function](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html)  (or a `for` loop) to extract the `x` and `y` fields from each cell's contents:

```
plot(cellfun(@(t) t.x, ans(1:98,1)), cellfun(@(t) t.y, ans(1:98,1)))
```

Note:

- `()` indexing is used instead of `{}`, because `cellfun` expects a cell array as input (more information about indexing cell arrays [here](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-cell-array.html)). Also, if you want to process the whole cell array you can skip indexing altogether and just use

  ```
  plot(cellfun(@(t) t.x, ans), cellfun(@(t) t.y, ans))
  ```
- The two anonymous functions `@(t) t.x` and `@(t) t.y` act on each cell's contents, namely a scalar struct, and extract from it the `x` or `y` field respectively. The results are packed by default into a standard (numerical) array by `cellfun`.

It would be much easier if your data were organized in a more convenient manner, such as a 98×1 struct array with fields `x` and `y`, or better yet two numeric vectors `x` and `y`.

Answer (score 6):

You can do what you want by

```
S = [ans{:}];
x = [S.x];
y = [S.y];
plot(x,y)
```

The first line converts the cell array into a struct array. `ans{:}` returns a comma-separated list of all elements in the cell array. The square brackets capture that, catenating all elements into a vector.

`S.x` again returns a comma-separated list. Here we catenate all x values into a numeric vector.

---

## Unsolicited advice

But please, please, please change how you store your data. Below I'll make a case for why you should.

Let's start with some random data in a structure similar to yours (a cell array where each element is a struct):

```
C = cell(1,100);
for ii=1:length(C)
   C{ii} = struct('x',randn(1),'y',randn(1),'z',randn(1),...
      'name',char('a'+floor(rand(1,10)*('z'-'a'+1))),...
      'status',rand(1)>0.3);
end
```

A better solution is a struct array:

```
S = [C{:}];
```

A struct array is a standard thing in MATLAB: it's an array where each element is an identical struct. You index these two somewhat differently:

```
>> C{5}
ans = 
  struct with fields:
         x: -0.0818
         y: 0.5463
         z: -0.8194
      name: 'ysrkqlzcms'
    status: 1

>> S(5)
ans = 
  struct with fields:
         x: -0.0818
         y: 0.5463
         z: -0.8194
      name: 'ysrkqlzcms'
    status: 1
```

Why is `S` a better solution than `C`?

#### A struct array is much more efficient memory wise

```
>> whos
  Name        Size              Bytes  Class     Attributes
  C           1x100            103700  cell                
  S           1x100             60820  struct
```

Note how `C` occupies almost double what `S` does. Why is this? `C` contains 100 structs, each struct stores some values, but also the names of those values. Thus, C stores 100 times the same names (in this case, `'x'`, `'y'`, `'z'`, `'name'` and `'status'`). `S` only stores those once.

#### A struct array is much easier to index.

That you needed to post this question proves this point. The first step in my answer was to convert the cell array to a struct array. Luis Mendo's answer shows how awkward it is to work with a cell array of structs.

#### A struct array is safer

You can do `C{5} = 'sorry'`, and prevent any sort of approach to use all `x` elements of the structs, because one of the cells no longer is a struct. `S(5)='sorry'` gives an error. This is to say, there is no way to enforce that all structs in your cell array of structs have the same elements. This complicates things significantly.

#### But there's an even better approach

Since MATLAB R2013b there is a `table` class. Objects of type `table` are even better than struct arrays.

```
T = struct2table(S);
```

A table stores each column as a single array, and therefore has a lot less overhead. That is, `T.x` is a single array, rather than `S.x` which is 100 arrays. This makes it much, much more efficient:

```
>> whos
  Name        Size              Bytes  Class     Attributes
  C           1x100            103700  cell                
  S           1x100             60820  struct              
  T         100x5               17476  table
```

Note how `T` uses 1/6 of the memory of `C`. This makes it also type safe: the `x` value for each row is guaranteed to be the same type and size. You cannot assign a string to one `x` value, nor anything that is not a scalar, if `x` is defined as a scalar double.

Indexing again is slightly different, but `T.x` directly gives you the array for all `x` values, and

```
>> T(5,:)
ans =
  1×5 table
    x           y          z            name        status
_________    _______    ________    ____________    ______
-0.081774    0.54633    -0.81939    'ysrkqlzcms'    true
```

So instead of indexing `C{5}.x` or `S(5).x`, you do `T.x(5)`.

Comment: Good idea! I knew there had to be a simpler way

Comment: +1 Nice and concise. It should also be mentioned that prior to 2013b there was a [`dataset`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/dataset-arrays.html) (now retired) that was similar to a table, and also a better option than structures and cell array.

Answer (score 0):

I also once had this problem for nested structure arrays (e.g., i wanted to plot kind of ans.x.y.z)

I posted some simple custom functions at my matlab file exchange:
[1]: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/116130-matlab-struct-operations

You can use following for the question

```
plotStructArray(ans,'x')
```