# Matlab - plot data from array of structs

Tags: matlab, plot

I have an array of structs. Every struct holds a set of data for one single measure. Matlab gives me an error when I try to plot this data.

```
Expected one output from a curly brace or dot indexing expression, but there were 361 results.
```

How should I rewrite my plot code?

```
plot(result.structArray_A(:).nonArrayValue_X, result.structArray_A(:).nonArrayValue_Y);
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ?

Comment: Please ping me if you do so I can remove my downvote

Comment: If `result.structArray_A` really is a struct array it should work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48133771/plotting-structure-array-in-matlab/48133906#48133906

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found a solution. Simply writing the following does work, even if the syntax does look odd:

```
plot([result.structArray_A.nonArrayValue_X], [result.structArray_A.nonArrayValue_Y]);
```